# Write a testcase using promises in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I just started using NodeJS and I am writing a UI test case.

I've been reading lot of online material but still, somehow am unable to figure out how to use promises for UI test cases.

I need to write a testcase (below scenario). I do not want to use `setTimeout`.

I am unable to figure out how to use promises in the below case.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),By = webdriver.By, until = 
webdriver.until;
var driver  = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
driver.get('http://www.*********url****');

driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('uid').setAttribute('value', 'u1')");
driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('pwd').setAttribute('value', 'pwd')");
driver.findElement(By.id('page1_login')).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.id('page2_navigator')).click();
driver.findElement(By.id('page2_my_tasks')).click();
driver.findElement(By.id('page3_create_task')).click();
driver.findElement(By.id('page3_submit_task')).click();
```

Comment: You don't seem to have an actual *question* here. What's the *problem* with what you've posted? Have you actually tried to use promises? What happened?

Comment: am basically failing to understand how to use promises here in this scenario.

Comment: Or to perhaps phrase it differently, it's not clear what you're trying to do here with Promises, why it's failing, what the intended behavior is, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: In discussing with nikoss, came across a great resource from MDN on [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). If you haven't worked with them before, this might be a good place to start.

---

Some APIs handle asynchronous calls with callbacks, others by returning a [Promise object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and some will give both options.

The selenium-webdriver module uses Promises, their API documentation can be found [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebElement.html). There are at least a couple options. You can build what's commonly called a Promise chain which would look roughly like this:

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build(); // returns Promise
driver
  .then(() => driver.get('http://www.*********url****')}) // IMPORTANT: return a Promise to continue the chain
  .then(() => driver.executeScript(...)})
  .then(() => driver.findElement(By.id('page1_login')).click()})
  // ...
  .catch((e) => { /** optionally catch errors here **/ });
```

If you're running on Node 7.5 or later, you can make use of [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). The result looks pretty close to what you had. Take note that your code still needs to be aware of which methods return a Promise and should `await` the Promise resolution before moving on to the next step.

```
(async function () => {
  var driver  = await new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build(); // await Promise here
  await driver.get('http://www.*********url****');
  await driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('uid').setAttribute('value', 'u1')");
  await driver.findElement(By.id('page1_login')).click();
  // ...
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

You are unclear how to use promises because this is not a case what promises are designed for.

First of all you say you want to use promises instead of `setTimeout` this is not possible because `setTimeout` is a function that defers execution of things minimum by given milliseconds.

Promises are a way to organize your code and chain following async calls which is just prettier then callbacks inside each other but that's it promises don't provide you with some sort of deferring structure.
Also check [this](http://es6-features.org/#PromiseUsage) out

Comment: i dont understand why i get a negative vote if you vote at least comment what do you think is wrong in the answer above

Comment: Promises are absolutely one of multiple ways to handle asynchronous calls. I also found the leading remark of your original answer callous and unhelpful to a new user.

Comment: @stealththeninja promises are a way to handle things those are asynchronous i still dont understand how could i possibly advise to use promises INSTEAD OF setTimeout they are two completely different things setTimout runs things at first possible tick after the given time can you tell me how is this connected to the promises at all ?

Comment: As I know them, setTimeout and setInterval used to be how we checked for async results when a callback wasn't an option. If you have a series of tasks, it gets complicated quick. Promises return an object _to which you attach a callback_, it inverts control to our benefit. I encourage you to read up on them and I'll be updating my answer with [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) doc from MDN.